# Black screen on boot, no keyboard

Tags: 12.04

I have been running Ubuntu for a couple years version 12.04. It has been working correctly and the only thing that I remember changing is to make it boot automatically for my wife. Now, it boots up with the following on the page in very small print:

`helentotten@ubuntujjtotten:"[]`

at least that is what it appears to be.  There could be " at the beginning before helen but I am not sure.

After it gets this far I am no longer able to input anything from the keyboard.  I have tried running GRUB in the recovery mode but it made no change.

I scrolled down to the following line:

```
Ubuntu 12.043, 2 LTS, kernel 3.2.0-30-generic (recovery mode)
```

There are actually several choices and I have tried all of them to no avail.

I don't have a clue how to get past this screen and enable keyboard input again.

I am just an inexperienced user and don't know much about Ubuntu

Comment: Try booting from a live CD/USB, to exclude hardware problems.

Comment: If it's a fresh install you can always just install again with a fresh copy of 12.04/13.04 to see if that works...

Comment: It sounds like its booting into tty what changes did you make when setting up the account for your wife

Comment: As I recall the only thing I did was to make it boot automatically bypassing the password.  The next thing I knew I could do no input from the keyboard.  I could still use GRUB though.